# How to have a multiview application in iOS 5 without using the storyboard?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, xcode4.2

I am a newbie to iPhone development. Could you please help me to understand how to create a multiview application without using the storyboard and tableview? Here is the scenario of my app, I have two views one is the login view (I am using the UINavigationController which contains the main login view and the NavigationBar is hidden) and the other one contains tabbed bar, the thing is I just can't switch to another view after the username and password are matched. Any help regarding this would be appreciable. Thanks alot in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Open **XCode**.

Go to **File** -> **New Project**

Choose either **Master-Detail Template** or **Utility Template**

Do NOT tick **Use Storyboard**

Look at the **code** and **learn**

OR

Google any tutorial on the web that was made for ios 4 (or earlier even) and use that.